# How to track all the 'Toasts' inside your Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio

Okay, so I am working on a project with my friend sequentially (he is a lousy coder).

Well there are couple of toasts he had left in the .java files of Android Studio project and they simply make our app looks bad.

One way is to revisit all those large number of .java files and view them line by line and comment the toast.

I am looking for a simpler solution. Is there any simple way to track or locate all the toasts in your Android Studio project?

Comment: the shortcut `ctrl + H` can search a keyword in the whole project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]Well, if you're using Android Studio as your IDE, you can simply select "Toast" and click "Find Usages" in the right-click menu.
Then, in the "Find" panel, you can see all the found usages and can navigate to the line by double clicking the found usage.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a Global search. Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>